# Not able to create a .htaccess file in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, web-hosting, digital-ocean

I recently tried to host an HTML5 website in digital ocean server (apache2 on ubuntu 16.04) and right now trying to implement .htaccess file for speed optimization.
I basically followed this instruction https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 where I disabled my 000-default.conf file with

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

and then created example.com.conf at /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf and enabled it. Here is the sample how it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My site is hosted inside /var/www/example.com/public_html/
Now I am unable to implement a .htaccess file.

I have activated htaceess by putting this code into example.com.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

And created .htaccess file inside /var/www/example.com and put this code

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

But when I do a speed test it still does not recognise browser leverage so I am pretty sure that .htaccess did not work. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the long post. I tried to give as many pieces of information as I can. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you use for your speed test?  I know the tools we use here do not care about the expiry headers since they want to test "raw", as if no one had the images cached.  There are options to change that however.  Have you tried with a browser in debug mode (F12 on Chrome) to see if you do get the headers or not?

Comment: Aah I just tried testing the htaccess file by puting garbage words and my websites give a 502 internal error. So that means htaccess file actually works. But no idea why browser leverage optimizations are still not working.

Comment: Must be at the tool's level then.